# Error. Fetching JSONP from ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jsonp

I am doing a cross-domain fetch from a ASP.NET page using Jquery-JSONP

My ASP.NET page looks like this;

```
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("functionName({'test_param':12345});");
        }
    }
```

This is hosted on my server as test.aspx

I am now using JQuery from localhost and trying to fetch the data from test.aspx like this;

```
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://abc.com/GTalk/test.aspx?callback=?',
                success: function () {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    alert("error" + x.responseText);
                }
            });
```

I am getting an error `x.responseText = "undefined"`
The error, z, is `Error: jQuery171008073005825281143_1328259709467`

I am not able to figure out what mistake I am doing. I am a newbie.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "functionName" on serverside you must print the function-name you receive via the GET-params as **callback**-parameter(**jQuery171008073005825281143_1328259709467** in that case).

You can't hardcode the name, it differs on every request)

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. To be more precise, jQuery sends the function via the `callback` query parameter. And he doesn't need to build the query parameter in his jQuery $.ajax object :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not claiming to be an expert here just an interested bystander.

From the previous post it looks as if the test harness is wrong i.e. your page. The difficulty being - how do you cope with the dynamic callback name? I've dug around a bit and I found an example that uses asmx webservices and httpmodules to get what you want.

[Accessing Remote ASP.Net webservices](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43038/Accessing-Remote-ASP-NET-Web-Services-Using-JSONP)

If I were you and would redo the test page as a webservice (sorry not very WCF I know) and wire in th module with your own method. Within the `JsonHttpModule` it looks like the `Write` method is doing the interesting work i.e. it is that that is wrapping the response write in a dynamic callback method signature that it is picking up from the query string (where JQuery will put it).

Unfortunately it looks like you've got a bit of work ahead of you to get it working. There might be better quicker ways but that all I found.

Comment: @Joy I see what you mean - mine's overengineered. I might just leave the post on anyway. I learnt something anyway